# Need to store integers from an ArrayList in as few containers as possible

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

Hello and thanks for your attention. 
Besides plane code I would like to know what process I should learn to design a solution for this type of problem.

I am given an `ArrayList<Integer> sample` containing integers and I need to put all those integers into objects that have a maximum capacity `int maxCapacity`, I should create as few objects as possible. I am free to choose the type of object that will contain the integer values.
 
*Sample list= [1,1,2,2,2,2,2,5,5,7,9,10]*
 
 *Maximum capacity = 10* 
 
 The desirable outcome for this sample should be:

Object 1 = [10] 
Object 2 = [9,1] 
Object 3 = [5,5] 
Object 4 = [7,2,1] 
Object 5 = [2,2,2,4]

 While I figure out the logic I am simply creating a new `ArrayList<Integer> output` and sorting the objects from the original list in the following way:

```
int groupSize = 1;


    int maxCapacity = 10;
    int value = 0;
    for(int i : sample) {
        if(i == maxCapacity) {
            output.add(i);
            sample.remove(i);
        }
    }
```

After compiling I get new input = [1,1,2,2,5,5,3,7,9] and new output = [10]

 Then I go to groups of 2

```
groupSize = 2

 boolean maxed = false;
        while (!maxed) {
            for (int i : input) {
                for (int j : input) {
                    if (maxVolume == i + j) {
                        output.add(i);
                        output.add(j);
                        input.remove(i);
                        input.remove(j);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i : input) {
                for (int j : input) {
                    if (maxVolume != i + j) {
                        maxed = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

I get new input = [1,2,2,3,7,] and new output = [10,9,1,5,5] 
 ... and so on, it gets too complicated with large lists and I shouldn't do it manually. So what do I need to do for *groupSize* to increase by one every time it gets all possible combinations? I've been trying loops inside loops and it started to get too messy

Comment: It is not clear how you go from the sample list (input) tou the desired output (Object[]). What type is the Object? Is the problem as simple as having a list of 10 elements, how to place these elements into 2 lists of max capacity of 5, etc?

Comment: I'm free to choose the object that will store the values. Each object has a maximum capacity of 10, I need to take the values from input and store them into as few containers(with max capacity 10) as possible  - so the sum of the integers contained by each the object cannot exceed 10

Comment: I created the output list just temporarily while figure out the logic. The final value of output should be= [10,9,1,5,5,7,21,2,2,2,4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the list is ordered, you first put number in a hashset.

Then you create two nested loops, with the inner loop going in the same direction as the outer loop and form groups such that the total is equal to max_number which is 10 in your case.

To find a total that equals to max, two checks are done:
1- Assuming that x + current total = max, we check if there is any occurrence to x in the set of numbers we have or not. If there is one, we add it to the group and we continue checking.
2- If not, we add a new item to the array and check the total.

This solution doesn't remove duplicates. You need to fix it to be cleaner to get you the solution you need.

```
    int MAX_NUMBER = 10;        
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,5,5,7,9,10);
     HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.addAll(list);
    HashSet<List<Integer>> groups = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++)
    {
        List<Integer> group = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        group.add(list.get(i));
        int total = list.get(i);
        boolean occurrence = set.contains(MAX_NUMBER - list.get(i));
        if (occurrence) {
            group.add(MAX_NUMBER - list.get(i));
            groups.add(group);

        }
            group = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            group.add(list.get(i));
            for (int j = i+1; j < list.size(); j++) {
                if ((total + list.get(j)) < MAX_NUMBER) {
                    total += list.get(j);
                    group.add(list.get(j));
                    occurrence = set.contains(MAX_NUMBER - total);
                    if (occurrence) {
                        List<Integer> groupClone = new ArrayList<>();
                        groupClone.addAll(group);
                        group.add(MAX_NUMBER - total);
                        groups.add(group);
                        group = groupClone;
                    }
                }
                 if (total + list.get(j) == MAX_NUMBER) {
                    group.add(list.get(j));
                    groups.add(group);
                    break;
                }
                 if (total > MAX_NUMBER)
                    break;
            }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to place all the numbers from the inputList into as few objects with max capacity of 10 or maxCapacity variable.

This can be done with the following code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int maxCapacity  = 10;
        List<Integer> inputList = Arrays.asList(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,5,5,7,9,10);
        List<List<Integer>> outputList=new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<inputList.size(); i+=maxCapacity){
            int remaining = inputList.size() - i;
            int maxIterations = 0;
            if (maxCapacity <= remaining){
                maxIterations = maxCapacity;
            }else{
                maxIterations = remaining;
            }
            List<Integer> internalL = new ArrayList<>(maxIterations);
            for (int ii=0; ii<maxIterations; ii++){
                internalL.add(inputList.get(i+ii));
            }
            outputList.add(internalL);
        }
        System.out.println("OutputList " + outputList);
   }
```

The above code includes a 2D List that contains Lists with initialCapacity and maxCapacity of 10. So the outputList will contain n Lists that each will contain up to 10 integers.

`for (int i=0; i<inputList.size(); i+=maxCapacity){`

In this outer loop the Object (at this case is the ArrayList of maxCapacity) will be created. The loop increments i by maxCapacity: 0, 10, 20, 30 etc. So for a initial List size of 12, this loop will iterate twice with i=0 and i=10.

Then the remaining is calculated as initialSize (12) - i. On the first iteration the remaining is 12 and on the second iteration the remaining is 2. This means that two List objects should be created with 10 and 2 numbers in each of the Lists.

To calculate the maximum iterations of the List object the maxCapacity should be chosen if the remaining items are more or equal to maxCapacity:

```
if (maxCapacity <= remaining){
    maxIterations = maxCapacity;
}else{
    maxIterations = remaining;
}
```

If the remaining are less than maxCapacity, then we need to iterate only for the remaining.

Finally, the second iteration gets from the inputList the object at index `i + ii` until it reaches the maxCapacity or remaining.

The output of your sample is

```
OutputList [[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 7], [9, 10]]
```

Meaning that there have been 2 List objects created the first with 10 objects and the second with 2 objects.